# return OR with the same value

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why would someone do this

`function() { return(abc || abc || "") }`

isn't it's enough to do just `return(abc || "")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, in any remotely serious code, doing just `return abc || ""` would be enough.

The only situation in which `return(abc || abc || "")` could possibly result in different logic would be if you were inside a `with`, or if `abc` was a getter on the window - and these would only occur if someone was deliberately writing confusing code.

```js
let count = 0;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'abc', { get: () => count++ });

const result = abc || "";
console.log(result);
```

```js
let count = 0;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'abc', { get: () => count++ });

const result = abc || abc || "";
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it took me few moments to understand that in this case the value of `abc` will have a different value each time it gets evaluated because it's not just a variable but it was defined as a property of the window object with a getter function attached to it. So when it's time to evalute the statement `abc || abc`, the first `abc` returns `0` and the second `abc` returns `1`, composing the expression `0 || 1`. I added this comment for further clarification and to say thank you for this nice demo.

Comment: Seriously!!! Now we have to think for this `getter` case as well every time we are going to use a `logical train`. :-) Nice reminder by the way. It's `javascript`.